# React Native sharing content

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn the basics of react native and have started with the basic tab template.  I am trying to create a social media sharing screen, where you get the list of apps and airdrop on iOS to display but unfortunately this is not working.  The code I have displays an empty view and I was expecting the share dialog to appear over the top.  I get the view but no sharing options.

Here is the code

`

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Share } from 'react-native';
var ActionSheetIOS = React;

export default class ShareScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Share',
    };

    showShareActionSheet() {
        ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions({
            url: 'https://www.someurl.org',
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                this.showShareActionSheet();
            </View>
        );
    }   
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
    },
});
```

`

any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your `this.showShareActionSheet();` with brackets to get it working.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    {this.showShareActionSheet()}
</View>
```

Otherwise it's gonna be considered as plain text and not as an instruction

Comment: thanks for the answer, it got me to an error 'ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions' is undefined - do I need to import this too? - I'm new to js too lol

Comment: Change your line var ActionSheetIOS = React; to var { ActionSheetIOS } = React;

Comment: I changed the ActionSheetIOS to Share.share and its working :)

Comment: Although its only working once and then doesn't display again :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share for sharing, This package will help you share the content to WhatsApp, FB, and other social apps.